# How to get triangle layout without using "polygon"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

[image: concept design image]

How to get triangle layout of 'mission' section within the container only without using "polygon". I don't want it to flow outside the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can make triangles using `border` property of css.

Check out this link for more shapes : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.mission {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}

.mission + div {
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="mission">
  </div>
  <div>
    Mission
  </div>
</div>
```